# Android app link not working on new update OS 12

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

I follow the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) for deep linking. When I test
the deep link using https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator I got sometimes attached error message and sometimes I got like attached success message and the same happened sometimes redirect me to the the browser and sometimes redirect me to the deep link page.

This is my manifest configuration

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com.qa"
                android:pathPrefix="/fb/fb" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com.qa"
                android:pathPrefix="/edocs/edocs" />
        </intent-filter>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you found the solution?

Comment: @Android_IT: based on their profile information, the question author has not signed in for at least a month. They may not receive your message.